# How can we remove "Authorization" Header from a 'HttpServletRequest'

Tags: java, servlets

How can we remove "Authorization" Header from a 'HttpServletRequest'.

We have 2 filters, after the first filter we need to remove the "Authorization" header from the request before passing the request to the second filter. I know we can add a header using

```
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

     HeaderMapRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HeaderMapRequestWrapper(req);

    //requestWrapper.addHeader("Authorization", "PPPPPPPP");

    requestWrapper.removeHeader("Authorization"); // Did not work

    public void removeHeader(String name) {
        headerMap.remove(name);
    }
```

But how can we remove "Authorization" Header.

Comment: Where is `HeaderMapRequestWrapper` coming from?  That's not a spec standard class.

Comment: public class HeaderMapRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible solution is to wrap the original request in a custom HttpServletRequestWrapper which overrides the `getHeader`, `getHeaders` and `getHeaderNames` methods:

```
request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    private Set<String> headerNameSet;

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        if (headerNameSet == null) {
            // first time this method is called, cache the wrapped request's header names:
            headerNameSet = new HashSet<>();
            Enumeration<String> wrappedHeaderNames = super.getHeaderNames();
            while (wrappedHeaderNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                String headerName = wrappedHeaderNames.nextElement();
                if (!"Authorization".equalsIgnoreCase(headerName)) {
                    headerNameSet.add(headerName);
                }
            }
        }
        return Collections.enumeration(headerNameSet);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
        if ("Authorization".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return Collections.<String>emptyEnumeration();
        }
        return super.getHeaders(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(String name) {
        if ("Authorization".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            return null;
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `HeaderMapRequestWrapper` is something that you implemented yourself, since it's not a spec standard and the only thing I can find about this class on google is this code example: http://www.codegithub.com/watch?v=0NByHgxUxPPU

Assuming that `HeadermapRequestWrapper` is a class that you copied from that code example, simply add a removeHeader() method.

```
public void removeHeader(String name) {
    headerMap.remove(name);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly I tried but not working. Let me debug more . Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: This would help to add a header to the request . headerMap does not contain all the request headers .